# Formatação de saída para colunas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

Necessito pegar a qtds de pgto de clientes temos cerca de 6 formas de pgto na loja, preciso retornar 2 deles em 1 coluna e o restante em outra coluna

Já tentei com subquerys e nada me retorna o esperado, a estrutura é basicamente:

```
/*
sog = table
ce = table
payment_method = coluna (onde estão os métodos de pgto)
entity_id = (id do cliente)
*/

SELECT
    ce.entity_id,
    sog.payment_method
        FROM magento.sales_order sog
        JOIN magento.customer_entity ce
        ON sog.customer_id=ce.entity_id
WHERE (
SELECT
    sog.payment_method
        FROM magento.sales_order_grid sog
WHERE sog.payment_method IN ('rede','multipayment_method'))
```

Comment: Pesquise por CASE.

Answer (score -3):

No seu caso, é melhor usar o CASE para sumarizar ou contar só quando safisfazer suas condições. No caso ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
SELECT
    ce.entity_id,
    sog.payment_method,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sog.payment_method IN ('rede','multipayment_method') THEN CampoValor ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN sog.payment_method NOT IN ('rede','multipayment_method') THEN CampoValor ELSE 0 END),
FROM magento.sales_order sog
JOIN magento.customer_entity ce ON sog.customer_id=ce.entity_id
```